# Hierarchical Bayesian model with heterogenous errors

Tags: bayesian, jags, hierarchical-bayesian

I have an experiment where I repeatedly show subjects two lights, and I ask which light is brighter. I am interested in whether error rates decrease over time, holding all else constant.

I also introduce a shock to the average brightness of the lights in the middle of the experiment. (For example, subjects are initially asked to choose between very dim lights for the first ten trials, and then subsequently need to choose between very bright lights for the next ten trials.)

I'm interested in constructing a hierarchical Bayesian model as follows:

$y_i = 1$ if $z_i > 0$

$y_i = 0$ if $z_i \leq 0$

where $y_i$ refers to the observed choice. (1 if the first light, 0 if the second light)

and the next layer is given by

$z_i = b_{1i} - b_{0i} + \epsilon_{i} $

where the $b$'s refer to objective brightness (in lumens). $b_{1i}$ refers to the brightness of the first light and $b_{0i}$ the second light.

Parameters are drawn from a distribution:

$\epsilon_{i}$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2 + \beta t + \kappa s)$

$t$ refers to the trial number and $s = 1$ on all trials after the shock. ($s = 0$ on all trials BEFORE the shock)

In other words, we are letting the variance of errors vary over time. Of key interest is whether $\beta < 0$ and $\kappa > 0$.

I intend to specify the prior distributions of both $\beta$ and $\kappa$ as standard normal and reject the null hypothesis if too many posterior distributions are far away from 0.

I"m wondering whether this approach, as well as allowing for heterogenous errors, is a valid way of doing Bayesian analysis? I've looked around and it seems that no one has done this before. Or am I treading new ground with a valid approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "no one has done this before"? This is a hierarchical Bayes model with an heteroskedastic probit sampling model and a change-point. It is unlikely that this model has not been analysed previously, even though the specific time heteroskedasticity (for the variance) may be new.

Comment: Thanks. I've never done Bayesian estimation before, so I guess I was looking in the wrong area. Would you be willing to give a quick opinion on whether (for a small dataset of a few hundred observations) SAS/STAT or jags is likely to be better for estimating this model (or are both equally suitable)?